# JavaScript: check if entire string is made up of repeatable pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a function that will return true if its input string matches a pattern and false if it doesn't. Sounds like a job for a regex to me.

The pattern is: `<something>:<number>-<number>;`

where `<something>` can be any combination of letters or numbers or blank. The pattern can repeat any number of times in the input string, and the `;` is optional for the last repetition of the pattern.

So these would return true:

- ABC:1-2;CDE:3-4
- ABC:1-2;CDE:3-4;
- ABC:1-2
- :1-2

but these would return false:

- ABC:1-2;cats;CDE:3-4
- ABC:1-2;CDE:3-4;cats

I've gotten that one repetition of the pattern could be represented with

`[\w\d\s]*:\d+-\d+;?`

but I'm struggling to find how to determine if the entire string is made up ONLY of repetitions of that pattern.

I've tried several things, including surrounding the pattern with `( )+` and/or `^ $`, but keep running into issues. What's the best way to check if a string is composed only of a pattern, repeated one or more times, in JavaScript?

Comment: hmm, surrounding it with `( )+` should have worked. Unless you have 1 or more spaces or newlines after the `;` character.

Comment: Is this `ABC:1-2CDE:3-4` and this `ABC:1-2  CDE:3-4FGH  :  77  -  77` true or false?

Comment: @KodosJohnson The problem with surrounding it with ( )+ was that the first failure, the one with cats in the middle, would be true to the equals() function because it finds two separate matching sequences, and there is no matches() javascript equivalent to test the entire string.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I would like those to be true, but it's not entirely necessary. Good catch, though. Accepting spaces is going on the to-do list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following expression:

```
/^[\w\s]*:\d+-\d+(?:;[\w\s]*:\d+-\d+)*;?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yIZmwq/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\w\s]*` - zero or more word or whitespace chars
- `:` - a colon
- `\d+-\d+` - 1 or more digits, `-` and again 1 or more digits
- `(?:;[\w\s]*:\d+-\d+)*` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `[\w\s]*:\d+-\d+` - the pattern described above
- `;?` - 1 or 0 `;`
- `$` - end of string.

Note that `[\w\d]` matches the same text as `\w`,thus, I suggest removing `\d` from `[\w\s]`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - *`;` is optional for the **last repetition of the pattern***

Comment: Actually, I should change the demo a bit: replace the `\s` with a space (since it is a multiline string there, not separate strings). Just for illustration - https://regex101.com/r/yIZmwq/3.

Comment: I know the multiline flag in the demo is just for illustration, but is the global flag left out of the answer on purpose?

Comment: I did not include it as I suppose you are processing strings one by one. Or do you have a multiline string input?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simpler regex:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*:\d+-\d+(?:;?$|;))+$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dKC9j9/2)

We keep trailing `;` optional at the end of each set which is:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]*:\d+-\d+;?` this matches 0 or more alphanumerics followed by `:` followed by digits-hyphen-digits.

Comment: Yes that should be a valid match as I understand the question.

Comment: *`;` is optional for the **last repetition of the pattern***

Comment: I am sure you know what 2 best practices your pattern does not follow. Besides, it is not in line with what OP needs.

Comment: Yes, use of `$` twice may seem strange but it avoids repetition of sub-pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9]*:\d+-\d+` and keeps regex shorter.

Comment: I did not mean that. You also should know "shorter" does not mean "efficient".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use + quantifier. Try the next approach:

```
function test(str) {
    return /^([\w\s]*:\d+-\d+;?)+$/.test(str)
  }
  console.log(test('ABC:1-2;CDE:3-4'));//true
  console.log(test('ABC:1-2;CDE:3-4;'));//true
  console.log(test('ABC:1-2'));//true
  console.log(test(':1-2'));//true
  console.log(test('ABC:1-2;cats;CDE:3-4'));//false
  console.log(test('ABC:1-2;CDE:3-4;cats'));//false
```